# FileOutputStream not creating xml document

Tags: android, xml, fileoutputstream

Hi i am trying to write create/update for a xml file but when i try to do it nothing happens. i am getting E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4097390 but do not if it related.

my Code:

```
 String XMLyPerson = "";
        try {
             XMLyPerson =  createXMLPerson(entries);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("exml.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            outputStreamWriter.write(XMLyPerson);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

xml method

```
public  static String createXMLPerson(List<Entry> list) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException
    {

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        xmlSerializer.setOutput(stringWriter);

        xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

        xmlSerializer.startTag(ns, "entries");
        for (Entry entry: list) {

            xmlSerializer.startTag(ns, "entry");

            xmlSerializer.startTag(ns, "title");
            xmlSerializer.text(entry.getTitle());
            xmlSerializer.endTag(ns, "title"); 
       for (Person p : entry.getVeiwers()) {

                xmlSerializer.startTag(ns, "reader");
                xmlSerializer.text(p.getName());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(ns, "reader");

            }
            xmlSerializer.endTag(ns, "entry");
        }
        xmlSerializer.endTag(ns,"entries");
        xmlSerializer.endDocument();
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Is it creating the file? Could be your code is crashing before it attempts to write it. Also it is good practice to call `fos.flush()` before closing.

Comment: no. as far as i can tell it not crashing and nothing it being caught in the try catch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the permissions for file writing in your android.manifest?

[Android persmissions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: the file still blank

Comment: Your XMLyPerson  string is empty after createXMLPerson is called?

Comment: does it matter if i have create the document or not?